# Javascript regex to clean email body

Tags: javascript, regex

I have about 100 raw emails containing text similar to following:

```
Seems alright now. You may proceed to file the same. 
Also, please update the status of TDS payment.
Thanks
---------- Forwarded message ---------- 
From: sender@email.com; 
Date: Tue, Mar 21, 2017 at 1:14 PM 
Subject: some subject 
To: abc@gmail.com 
Cc: xyz@ymail.com
```

What I need to do is to remove forwarded message part from each email and only retain the text written by sender.

**Expected Output:**

```
Seems alright now. You may proceed to file the same. 
Also, please update the status of TDS payment.
Thanks
```

What regex pattern can I use to achieve the expected output??

Comment: See [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739)

Comment: If you add what you have tried so far then it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
^(?=.*Forwarded message)[^]*
```

i.e in javascript:

```
'/^(?=.*Forwarded message)[^]*/m;'
```

> Update

You can also try the following regex if you need to consider `-`:

```
^(?=\s*[-]+\s*Forwarded message\s*[-]+\s*)[^]*
```

Replace by:

"" empty

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/16)

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*Forwarded message)[^]*/m;
const str = `Seems alright now. You may proceed to file the same. 
Also, please update the status of TDS payment.
Thanks
---------- Forwarded message ---------- 
From: sender@email.com; 
Date: Tue, Mar 21, 2017 at 1:14 PM 
Subject: some subject 
To: abc@gmail.com 
Cc: xyz@ymail.com

What I need to do is to remove forwarded message part from each email and only retain the text written by sender.

Expected Output:

Seems alright now. You may proceed to file the same. 
Also, please update the status of TDS payment.
Thanks`;
const subst = ``;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why `g` modifier?

Comment: Note that this will not work when the message itself contains the string "Forwarded message".

Comment: @revo forgot to remove that initially... removed.  Str definitely you are right but the thing is, it should work in 99% case if that is how the op's mail appears... we can continue to improve it... you can not even stop at "Thanks" either :)

Comment: @str moreover the op has mentioned that : "I have about 100 raw emails containing text similar to following: "

Comment: I would rather use `^(---------- Forwarded message ----------)[^]*` to be sure.

Comment: For improving it, I suggest you to a put a dash `-` right after caret. This way engine fails quickly if it begins a line which is not the right one. Also change regex inside lookahead to strictly demonstrate header line: `^-(?=-* Forwarded message)[^]*`

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman If you want to make this generic, then I would really use the regex I posted. Your updated expression also matches everything starting from "- Forwarded message". I can totally see scenarios where this might not be what you want (e.g. an email containing "- Forwarded message contains XYZ").

Comment: Hey, thanks everyone for the help..actually I am new to regex..using your codes and guidance, I can now customise it further to suit my needs.

Comment: It doesn't matter if message body contains `Forwarded message` or `---------- Forwarded message ----------`. A regex for trimming content may match both. You are just going the long way. Your regex is not optimal either. @str

Comment: @revo There is no way we can make an optimal solution without knowing the exact circumstances. However, I guess that an email containing "-[..]- Forwarded message -[..]-" is much less likely than "- Forwarded message".

Comment: Yes and that's why I said you are going the long way only. If first pattern was unreliable, then yours is as well. The difference is, you are forcing engine to advance character by character which takes a little more time. @str